# solving 2d Heat equation : $\nabla^2 w = - Kw$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I've been trying to solve the following 2D Heat equation but I'm not sure it is right,
$$
\partial^2_x w + \partial^2_y w = - Kw
$$

with the following boundary conditions,
$$
w(0,y) = w(L_1,y) = 0, \quad \forall y \in [0, L_2]
$$
$$
w(x,0) = w(x, L_2) = 0, \quad \forall x \in [0,L_1]
$$

#### Separation of variables

$$
w(x,y) = u(x)v(y)
$$

We can rewrite the boundary conditions,
\begin{align*}
w(0,y) = u(0)v(y) &\implies u(0) = 0 \\
w(L_1,y) = u(L_1)v(y) &\implies u(L_1) = 0 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
w(x,0) = u(x)v(0) &\implies v(0) = 0 \\
w(x,L_2) = u(x)v(L_2) &\implies v(L_2) = 0 
\end{align*}

Applying the separation of variables,
$$
u''(x)v(y) + u(x)v''(y) = -Ku(x)v(y) \implies u''(x)v(y) = -u(x)(Kv(y) + v''(y))
$$
$$
\frac{u''(x)}{u(x)} = - \left(K + \frac{v''(y)}{v(y)}\right) = -k^2
$$

Therefore we have,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
u''(x) = -k^2 u(x) &\implies u(x) = A\cos(kx) + B\sin(kx) \\
v''(y) = (k^2 - K) v(y) &\implies v(y) = Ce^{-\eta y} + De^{\eta y}; \quad \eta^2 = (k^2 - K)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Applying the boundary conditions,
\begin{align*}
u(0) = 0 &\implies A = 0 \\
u(L_1) = 0 &\implies B\sin(kL_1) = 0 \implies kL_1 = n\pi \implies k = \frac{n\pi}{L_1}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
v(0) = 0 &\implies C = -D \\
v(L_2) = 0 &\implies 2D \sinh(\eta L_2) = 0 \implies \eta L_2 = 0 \implies \sqrt{(k^2 - K)}L_2 = 0 \implies k^2 = K
\end{align*}

So the solution would be
$$
w(x,y) = B\sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L_1} \right)(C-D)
$$

I don't think it's correct, isn't it ?

Comment: No, it isn't correct. You found that $2D \sinh(\eta y) = 0$, but this implies $\eta y = 0 \text{ or } \color{red}{D = 0}$. If $\eta y = 0 \ \forall y$, then $\eta = 0 \implies k^{2} - K = 0$. But $K$ is arbitrary, so you must have $D = 0$, which then implies $v(y) \equiv 0$ and hence $w = 0$.

Comment: But $w(x,y)$ cannot be $0$, I mean it is the trivial solution.

Comment: Irrespective of whether it is trivial or not, it is _the_ solution. You've shown it yourself (almost).

Comment: Btw, I just noticed that the exercice asks "such a solution exists for all value of $K$ ?". Which I could say that the solution I wrote exists for $K = k^2$ otherwise for all other values of $K$, $w(x,y) = 0$ ?